# hooking up a bathroom light

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have a three switch wall plate, left is overhead light, middle is the bathroom fan, and third is the vanity light on the wall. I removed the vanity light, and I find 4 wires, two white, and two black. The short white is hot, and the short black one is hot. My new light has a white and a black wire, plus a neutral. How do I connect them?

Comment: How was the old light connected?

Comment: You connect them the same way the old vanity light was connected. Don't get creative or experimental...

Comment: What colour is the wire you are calling neutral?  White is usually neutral(most cases), black is hot, and green or bare copper/Al is ground.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?